# React data-table-component: onClick on button doesn't work on inner icon

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

I'm using the `react-data-table-component`.

I have these columns:

```js
const columns = [
        {
            name: 'ID',
            selector: 'id',
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'Place',
            selector: 'place',
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'Created at',
            sortable: true,
            selector: 'created_at',
            cell: row => new Date(row.created_at).toLocaleDateString()
        },
        {
            name: '',
            sortable: false,
            cell: () => <Button variant="danger" data-tag="allowRowEvents" data-action="delete"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} /></Button>,
        }
    ]
```

And in `Datatable` component:

```js
const handleRowClicked = ({id}, e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        const action = e.target.getAttribute('data-action')
        switch (action) {
            case 'show':
                props.openModalDetail(id);
            break;
            case 'delete':
                props.delete(id)
            break
            default:
                return
        }
        return
    }
```

The event is listend on click on button (every pixel of red square) but not on icon itself.

[image]

I did try to add the `data-tag="allowRowEvents"` on icon itself, without success.

I did try to add a listener to `e.currentTarget`, without success.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation has information about that [React data-table-component: onClick on button doesn't work on inner icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67799756/react-data-table-component-onclick-on-button-doesnt-work-on-inner-icon) On *onRowClicked* section they say that:

> Note: If you are using custom cells (column[].cell), you will need to apply the data-tag="allowRowEvents" to the innermost element or on the elements you want to propagate the onRowClicked event to.

Important part *is apply the data-tag="allowRowEvents" to the **innermost** element*. So I think you must add this element to the * FontAwesomeIcon* component too.